# Alternative methods of compilation?

Tags: compiler-construction

I've been learning about compilers for a few years (and related topics like programming language design) and have come to understand that most compilers you'll see out there follow the basic design of:

1. Lexical Analysis
2. Syntax/Semantic Parsing
3. AST Generation
4. Code Generation

Of course, there is a lot of freedom in how you follow and implement these steps, but to some extent, this is a compiler's basic scheme. My question is, especially with so many new functional programming languages and methodologies, are there other methods of compiling source code? Methods that theoretically work as well as the ones listed but follow a completely different scheme. In addition to answers, I would also appreciate articles, books, etc. for more information on this. Thanks and have a happy new years!

Comment: See my Quora answer to the question *What are the most important concepts to understand about compilers?*  https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-most-important-concepts-to-understand-about-compilers/answer/Ira-Baxter.  No point in copying here; that just makes duplicates.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it?

Comment: The answer is "yes, but they aren't as robust at error handling which is why they aren't used".

Answer (score 1):

Most of the work of a real-world optimizing compiler happens between steps 3 (AST generation) & 4 (code emisson). For GCC, that covers more than three fourth of it 15 millions lines.

The Ocaml compiler also has several internal transformation changes between these two steps. Notably, a type inference step is transforming some untyped AST into a typed AST. Read about [A-normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form) & [Continuation Passing Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

In fact, a compiler is transforming a lot many internal representations, up to the final emitted ouput (e.g. assembler code).

Look at my references & slides on http://gcc-melt.org/docum.html for much more.

If you know some Scheme or Lisp dialect, read Queinnec's [Lisp In Small Pieces](https://pages.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) book, it explores many ways of implementing Lisp interpreters & compilers.

See also J.Pitrat's [blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/): his CAIA system has several transformations of internal representations from more declarative forms to more procedural forms.

Answer (score 0):

### Why do we categorize these steps

In the end, the main reason we divide these tasks into categories is to make it easier to understand the complexity of a compiler. These tasks are all necessary for any language processing (even for non-programming languages), although sometimes they are so trivial we tend to forget about them (For example some scripting languages don't really "generate code", once they have executable byte-code, they just interpret it, but you can still argue these programming languages "compile" to byte-code. Shell languages often don't really have an explicit "AST").

### Can we write a compiler that does these steps differently

A language/compiler could be written in such a way that it never explicitly does one (or more) of these steps, but in the end it still does all of them one way or another. A classic example is Machine Code. CPU's still have to lex and parse it, modern CPU's even perform the "Code Generation/Optimization" step with branch prediction and micro-code. "lexing" is the equivalent of looking up a byte in a instruction table, and the "AST" is perhaps nothing more than one or two internal registers used for remembering instruction operands.

### Why don't we write our compilers differently

There are also other benefit to separating these steps in our code so we can run them in parallel, or at least on demand.

Lexical Analysis takes (perhaps surprisingly) much more time than Parsing/AST Generation for most modern programming languages because of the large amount of data (easily billions of characters compared to a couple hundred thousand tokens), but after that, constant folding, type checking, assembly optimization and register allocation take over the execution time of a compiler again.

By separating these steps, we can optimize the overall process, for example by lexing, parsing, and compiling one function per thread. In fact, after we have an AST, some code generation and optimizations can again run in parallel. Your "Code Generation" step could therefore again be meaningfully separated into many different smaller optimization and generation steps which allows us to think about the compiler in even more detail. We might then be able to run some of these smaller steps in parallel also. JIT compilers are very good at this, and it makes them much faster than your typical compiler. But in the end, they still have to perform all of the basic steps you keep hearing about.